# Unique downloadable sales - is it possible?

Tags: downloadable, upload

Business model is as follows:

1. Customer uploads a file (PDF/XLS)
2. Customer pays for our services through one of the payment gateways
3. We use the information from the file to manually create a unique PDF for the customer
4. We upload the resulting file to customer panel
5. File is emailed to the customer + customer is able to login and download it

Is this doable with Magento and extensions, without writing our own?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you're going to find a way to do this without some customization.

Downloadable products allow you to specify a URL instead of uploading a specific file. I think you should be able to use that to have the customer hit a url such as: `example.com/customfile/download` when they are logged in. This custom controller would have some logic to check the current customer and then provide a list of files you've uploaded. The files would probably need to be a custom model that contains a handful of fields, likely: customer_id, file_url, file_name, etc ...

Some semi-pseudo code might look like:

```
// Controller
$customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
$files = Mage::helper('my_custom_helper')->getCustomerFiles($customer);


// Helper/Model (up to you to decide how to organize the module)
public function getCustomerFiles($customer){
    $files = Mage::getModel('my_custom_files_model')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', array('eq' => $customer->getId()));
    return $files;
}
```

For the files model/collection, you can search on how to build custom models/collections. The Ulimate Module Creator might be of some help here.